# Link onclick and Focus on Image in the nextpage

Tags: javascript

What i am trying to do:

I have a link which links to "Enquiry Page", here is my html for the link:

```
<a href="enquiry.html" id="sroom1"> ENQUIRY | </a>
```

And this is the image (which I already used anchor element to make it focus when it is clicked) in enquiry page I want it to stay focus when the link above is clicked to access enquiry page:

```
<a class="ananchor" href="#ol" id="imageeee111"><img src="images2/exterior.jpg" alt="Apartment 1" class="an2image" ></a>
```

And this is my Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("sroom1").onclick = function(){myClickFunction()};
function myClickFunction(){
    document.getElementById("imageeee111").focus();
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: When the link is clicked, the browser leaves the current page and goes to `enquiry.html`. How can it "stay in focus" when **it no longer exists**!

Comment: @Quentin Thank You! But like after the link is clicked to move to enquiry page and the image in enquiry page becomes focus? It is not possible?.